# Randomize Utilities.sleep function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to randomize Utilities.sleep function in Google Script?
I have a Google sheets with shortening link function. The script is like below:

```
function ShortURL(longUrl) {
  const url = "http://example.com/api/url/add";
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: { Authorization: "Token MYTOKEN" },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "url": longUrl
    })
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var shortUrl = JSON.parse(res.getContentText()).short;
  Logger.log(shortUrl);
  return shortUrl;}
```

But when I run it (Fetch about 100 urls), it throws me error:

> Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch. (line
> 11).

After search and asking in the Stackoverflow, They suggest me to use `Utilities.sleep(5000);`

So the code become like this:

```
function ShortURL(longUrl) {
  const url = "http://example.com/api/url/add";
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: { Authorization: "Token MYTOKEN" },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "url": longUrl
    })
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var shortUrl = JSON.parse(res.getContentText()).short;
  Logger.log(shortUrl);
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  return shortUrl;}
```

But, It just pending the errors for 5 seconds. How can I randomize the value of `Utilities.sleep(5000);`?

something like:

```
Utilities.sleep(RANDOM_FROM_1MINS-5MIN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Math.random()](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_random.asp) to generate a random number. In your case, considering the interval between 1 and 5 minutes, you can use:

```
const min = 60000; // milliseconds in one minute
const max = 300000; // milliseconds in five minutes
const waitTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
Utilities.sleep(waitTime);
```

Mind that a script can only run for [six minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) at a time, so using 5 minutes probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: I will try and modify to 3 minutes. Will let you know later

Comment: It works nicely! But the custom function only works 30s. So I modified the max to 20000 to give extra 10seconds for the script. Thank you so much!